# How to redirect domain to external IP address using HTTPD

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Let's say I have some domain - mydomain.com, and I want to redirect it to some IP address of another server, but preserve the domain in the address bar... how would I do this in my httpd.conf file? The following code I found does not work:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://123.123.123.12"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://123.123.123.12"
    ServerName mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you need to match trailing slashes. Also that's called "reverse proxy", not exactly a "redirect". "Virtualhost *:* is a bad idea, use *:port or ip:port instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied

`<VirtualHost 123.123.123.12>
  ServerName mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to still not be working. When I ping the domain, mydomain.com, I get "Request timed out."